# GeoServer WPS process fail with OpenLayers 2: "The request body should be contained in a CDATA section"

Tags: geoserver, geoprocessing, openlayers-2, wps

I am trying to create an application with WPS builder like this: http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13.1/examples/wps.html
When input format = "text/xml; subtype=wfs-collection/1.0", it creates input field for name of the layer on my server:

```
function addWFSCollectionInput(input) {
var name = input.identifier;
var field = document.createElement("input");
field.title = input["abstract"];
field.value = name + " (layer on the server)";
addValueHandlers(field, function() {
    input.reference = field.value ? {
        mimeType: "text/xml; subtype=wfs-collection/1.0",
        href: "http://46.28.111.137:8080/geoserver2711/wfs",
        method: "POST",
        body: {
            wfs: {
                version: "1.0.0",
                outputFormat: "GML2",
                featureType: field.value
            }
        }
    } : undefined;
});
document.getElementById("input").appendChild(field);
```

}

This input is required for example by algorithms gs:Clip and gs:Aggregate. When I'm trying to run some of these algorithms, it returns this kind of result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><wps:ExecuteResponse xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wps="http://www.opengis.net/wps/1.0.0" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:lang="en" service="WPS" serviceInstance="http://46.28.111.137:8080/geoserver2711/ows?" version="1.0.0"><wps:Process wps:processVersion="1.0.0"><ows:Identifier>gs:Clip</ows:Identifier><ows:Title>Clip</ows:Title><ows:Abstract>Clips (crops) features to a given geometry</ows:Abstract></wps:Process><wps:Status creationTime="2015-08-25T08:35:59.568Z"><wps:ProcessFailed><ows:ExceptionReport version="1.1.0"><ows:Exception exceptionCode="NoApplicableCode"><ows:ExceptionText>The request body should be contained in a CDATA section, otherwise it will get parsed as XML instead of being preserved as is</ows:ExceptionText></ows:Exception></ows:ExceptionReport></wps:ProcessFailed></wps:Status></wps:ExecuteResponse>
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: did you try enclosing your xml payload in a CDATA block?

Comment: Would we have to add the cdata tag manually into the input, or can we modify the js to do it for us?